# How to json_decode multiple arrays together?

Tags: php, php-5.5

I'm using multi curl to download multiple URLs and parse them using foreach loop. Here is the structure of those responses (print_r result):

```
Array(

[0] => {
     "Animals": [{
         "Number": 1,
         "AnimalName": Lion
     }],
     "Continents": [{
         "ContinentName": Africa
     }]
 }
 [1] => {
     "Animals": [{
         "Number": 1,
         "AnimalName": Tiger
     }],
     "Continents": [{
         "ContinentName": Africa
     }]
 }
 [2] => {
     "Animals": [{
         "Number": 1,
         "AnimalName": Leopard
     }],
     "Continents": [{
         "ContinentName": Africa
     }]
 }

 )
```

Considering that all of the responses have the same or almost the same structure, I would like to process all of them together. Or, even better, choose which ones to process together (an example could be to group arrays 1-2 and 3-5 together).

In this case I need to change some words with str_replace (that works well with this code), then json_decode it and parse everything using foreach loop. Unfortunately, it seems that json_decode doesn't work that way and I don't get any results with foreach loop. If I add array's number in the form of `json_decode($res[0], true);`, then results are displayed. Here is the whole code:

```
<?php

$downloads = array(
"http://www.example.com/1",
"http://www.example.com/2",
"http://www.example.com/3"
);

$mh = curl_multi_init();

foreach ($downloads as $i => $download) {
 $connection[$i]=curl_init($download);
 curl_setopt($connection[$i], CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
 curl_setopt($connection[$i], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($connection[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
 curl_multi_add_handle ($mh,$connection[$i]);
}

do {
  $n=curl_multi_exec($mh,$active);
  curl_multi_select($mh, 0.7);
} while ($active);

foreach ($downloads as $i => $download) {
 $res[$i]=curl_multi_getcontent($connection[$i]);
 curl_multi_remove_handle($mh,$connection[$i]);
 curl_close($connection[$i]);
}
curl_multi_close($mh);

$old = array('Cat', 'Lion');
$new = array('Dog', 'Tiger');
$resultsall = str_replace($old, $new, $res);

$resultsall = (array) json_decode($res, true); // How to make this work?

// These work:
$results1 = json_decode($res[0], true);
$results2 = json_decode($res[1], true);
$results3 = json_decode($res[2], true);


// This doesn't output anything:
foreach($resultsall['Animals'] as $val1)
{ echo $val1['AnimalName']; }

// This works well:
foreach($results1['Animals'] as $val2)
{ echo $val2['AnimalName']; }

?>
```

Is there a way to do all of json_decoding at once? I feel like it's a very simple change in the code, but all of the changes I have tried didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json_decode` expects *a string* as its input. If you're giving it an array instead, it has no idea what to do with that. You will simply have to loop and call `json_decode` on each string in your array individually. A shorthand wrapper for this kind of an operation is an array map:

```
$resultsall = array_map('json_decode', $res);
```

Though if you want to pass additional arguments, it'll need to be:

```
$resultsall = array_map(function ($json) { return json_decode($json, true); }, $res);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. So in my case it should be `$resultsall = array_map(function ($json) { return json_decode($json, true); }, $res[0], $res[1]);`? I have tried that but didn't get any output either. I have tried also with only `$res[0]` or `$res`, but there's no output at all.

Comment: No. The code as shown should work. I didn't say anything about `$res[0]`.

Comment: If I do `print_r($resultsall);`, it does display the new code. But foreach loop still doesn't work with it. How should I adjust it?

Comment: `foreach ($resultsall as $result) foreach ($result['Animals'] as $animal) echo $animal['AnimalName'];` – perhaps because you need two nested loops?

Comment: Thank you, that's the solution I was looking for! Just one more question please, regarding performance - is this solution more performant than what I used before (`$results1 = json_decode($res[0], true); $results2 = json_decode($res[1], true); $results3 = json_decode($res[2], true); ...`)

Comment: Not more performant at all; but more sensible and it won't drive you nuts as you need to write more and more code for more and more arrays.

Comment: That's fine, I only want to avoid it being much slower than the old solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$mergedArray = array_merge($firstArray, $secondArray)` the two array's are merged into one and accesible via `$mergedArray`. Please note that the array_keys will be renumbered.

Comment: Tried this, but there's no output: `$mergeresults = array_merge($res[0], $res[1], $res[2]); $resultsall = json_decode($mergeresults, true);`